# How to convert 7.4mm x 5.0mm DC jack to USB Type C?

Tags: usb, macbook, macbook-pro, charger, usb-3.1-type-c

Yesterday my Macbook pro (USB Type C) charger stopped working. As we are in lockdown I am unable to buy a new one. What I tried-: I have a 7.4mm x 5.0 mm HP laptop charger. I cut a USB 2 to Type C cable and tried to connect its red wire to the outer diameter and red wire to the inner diameter of 7.4mm x 5.0 mm HP laptop charger. It became like 7.4mm x 5.0 mm to type C. But unfortunately, it did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your MacBook Pro probbably requires that the charger authenticates itself before charging. Furthermore, as ther is not an standard for USB-C devices, **DO NOT TRY to make a DIY charger**. It's extremely dangerous.
Instead, try to buy a charger on the internet.

Comment: That is a good way to destroy your laptop USB circuitry. USB Power Delivery is an actively negotiated connection and has a data line to talk to the power supply. The devices start out at 5V and negotiate up to the maximum supply. Simply blasting up to 19V down the cable may not be the best thing.

Comment: This is not only a good way to destroy the USB circuity on your device, it's a good way to fry the entire motherboard, you really should avoid making DIY cables.  Most stores  (Bestbuy, Walmart, etc) are offering an option for curbside pickup.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not try to alter non-Apple equipment to provide power to an Apple PC. It will void your warranty. Instead, order a replacement power supply.